# Laravel 10 - ViewServiceProvider doesn't have access to auth user

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

How can I get auth user in `ViewServiceProvider`? At the moment `auth()->user()` is returning null, and I need to access it in the **MenuComposer** class. How can I do this?

**confing/app.php**

```
'providers' => ServiceProvider::defaultProviders()->merge([
        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\ViewServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\BladeServiceProvider::class,
    ])->toArray(),
```

I have following **ViewServiceProvider**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\View\Composers\ColorSchemeComposer;
use App\View\Composers\DarkModeComposer;
use App\View\Composers\FakerComposer;
use App\View\Composers\LoggedInUserComposer;
use App\View\Composers\MenuComposer;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

    class ViewServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        /**
         * Register any application services.
         */
        public function register(): void
        {
            //
        }
    
        /**
         * Bootstrap any application services.
         */
        public function boot(): void
        {
            View::composer('*', MenuComposer::class);
            View::composer('*', FakerComposer::class);
            View::composer('*', DarkModeComposer::class);
            View::composer('*', LoggedInUserComposer::class);
            View::composer('*', ColorSchemeComposer::class);
        }
    }
```

MenuComposer class:

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Composers;

use App\Main\SideMenu;
use App\Main\SimpleMenu;
use App\Main\TopMenu;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class MenuComposer
{
    /**
     * Bind menu to the view.
     */
    public function compose(View $view): void
    {
        if (! is_null(request()->route())) {
            $pageName = request()->route()->getName();
            $layout = $this->layout($view);
            $activeMenu = $this->activeMenu($pageName, $layout);

            $view->with('topMenu', TopMenu::menu());
            $view->with('sideMenu', SideMenu::menu());
            $view->with('simpleMenu', SimpleMenu::menu());
            $view->with('firstLevelActiveIndex', $activeMenu['first_level_active_index']);
            $view->with('secondLevelActiveIndex', $activeMenu['second_level_active_index']);
            $view->with('thirdLevelActiveIndex', $activeMenu['third_level_active_index']);
            $view->with('pageName', $pageName);
            $view->with('layout', $layout);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Specify used layout.
     */
    public function layout($view): string
    {
        if (isset($view->layout)) {
            return $view->layout;
        } elseif (request()->has('layout')) {
            return request()->query('layout');
        }

        return 'side-menu';
    }

    /**
     * Determine active menu & submenu.
     */
    public function activeMenu($pageName, $layout): array
    {
        $firstLevelActiveIndex = '';
        $secondLevelActiveIndex = '';
        $thirdLevelActiveIndex = '';

        if ($layout == 'top-menu') {
            foreach (TopMenu::menu() as $menuKey => $menu) {
                if (isset($menu['route_name']) && $menu['route_name'] == $pageName && empty($firstPageName)) {
                    $firstLevelActiveIndex = $menuKey;
                }

                if (isset($menu['sub_menu'])) {
                    foreach ($menu['sub_menu'] as $subMenuKey => $subMenu) {
                        if (isset($subMenu['route_name']) && $subMenu['route_name'] == $pageName && $menuKey != 'menu-layout' && empty($secondPageName)) {
                            $firstLevelActiveIndex = $menuKey;
                            $secondLevelActiveIndex = $subMenuKey;
                        }

                        if (isset($subMenu['sub_menu'])) {
                            foreach ($subMenu['sub_menu'] as $lastSubMenuKey => $lastSubMenu) {
                                if (isset($lastSubMenu['route_name']) && $lastSubMenu['route_name'] == $pageName) {
                                    $firstLevelActiveIndex = $menuKey;
                                    $secondLevelActiveIndex = $subMenuKey;
                                    $thirdLevelActiveIndex = $lastSubMenuKey;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } elseif ($layout == 'simple-menu') {
            foreach (SimpleMenu::menu() as $menuKey => $menu) {
                if ($menu !== 'divider' && isset($menu['route_name']) && $menu['route_name'] == $pageName && empty($firstPageName)) {
                    $firstLevelActiveIndex = $menuKey;
                }

                if (isset($menu['sub_menu'])) {
                    foreach ($menu['sub_menu'] as $subMenuKey => $subMenu) {
                        if (isset($subMenu['route_name']) && $subMenu['route_name'] == $pageName && $menuKey != 'menu-layout' && empty($secondPageName)) {
                            $firstLevelActiveIndex = $menuKey;
                            $secondLevelActiveIndex = $subMenuKey;
                        }

                        if (isset($subMenu['sub_menu'])) {
                            foreach ($subMenu['sub_menu'] as $lastSubMenuKey => $lastSubMenu) {
                                if (isset($lastSubMenu['route_name']) && $lastSubMenu['route_name'] == $pageName) {
                                    $firstLevelActiveIndex = $menuKey;
                                    $secondLevelActiveIndex = $subMenuKey;
                                    $thirdLevelActiveIndex = $lastSubMenuKey;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            foreach (SideMenu::menu() as $menuKey => $menu) {
                if ($menu !== 'divider' && isset($menu['route_name']) && $menu['route_name'] == $pageName && empty($firstPageName)) {
                    $firstLevelActiveIndex = $menuKey;
                }

                if (isset($menu['sub_menu'])) {
                    foreach ($menu['sub_menu'] as $subMenuKey => $subMenu) {
                        if (isset($subMenu['route_name']) && $subMenu['route_name'] == $pageName && $menuKey != 'menu-layout' && empty($secondPageName)) {
                            $firstLevelActiveIndex = $menuKey;
                            $secondLevelActiveIndex = $subMenuKey;
                        }

                        if (isset($subMenu['sub_menu'])) {
                            foreach ($subMenu['sub_menu'] as $lastSubMenuKey => $lastSubMenu) {
                                if (isset($lastSubMenu['route_name']) && $lastSubMenu['route_name'] == $pageName) {
                                    $firstLevelActiveIndex = $menuKey;
                                    $secondLevelActiveIndex = $subMenuKey;
                                    $thirdLevelActiveIndex = $lastSubMenuKey;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return [
            'first_level_active_index' => $firstLevelActiveIndex,
            'second_level_active_index' => $secondLevelActiveIndex,
            'third_level_active_index' => $thirdLevelActiveIndex,
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: no where are you calling `auth()->user()` in your code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Auth or auth functions, you should add related class at the top of your providers list as below:

```
Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
```

So your code should be something like this:

```
'providers' => ServiceProvider::defaultProviders()->merge([
    /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\ViewServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\BladeServiceProvider::class,
])->toArray(),
```

Or extend your custom auth provider using laravel auth provider.